# Windows active directory authentication for asp.net intranet app in iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

We have several existing applications for our business that use AD authentication with IIS. Everything is working as intended on Windows, but on the iPad's we are prompted to login for every single web application on every single refresh or submit. The page will load when credentials are entered, but when we navigate to another page we are prompted for credentials again. Is there any way for iOS device to store these credentials, or info about the domain?

I will add that the business wifi we're using requires the credentials to connect.. is there a way to grab the information from the connection? I have searched the web several hours today and found some similar questions on stack overflow,  but nothing with a working solution.

Comment: Can you provide more information - Are these web apps that you are accessing with Safari? Or have you built iOS native apps?  If it is just Safari then I would look at the cookies that you are issuing to track session state - Do they have appropriate expiration dates and is the domain correct for the site that is being accessed.  Safari can block cross-domain cookies to limit tracking.  You can't use the Wifi credentials for single sign on.  You can update your web apps to support OAuth and then use SSO

Comment: These are webapps and I've tried accessing with Safari, Chrome and Edge on the iPads. I *think* I have the settings to not block cookies but I'll have to check tomorrow when I return to work because I forgot the iPad :(. Updating the apps to support OAuth would be a huge under-taking as there are over 100 of them, but if there is no "simple" solution then we may have to look into something along those lines

Comment: Regardless of which browser you use on iOS, it is Apple's webkit under the skin, so the actual browser behaviour will be identical.